Error module spyne.six.moves, execute serve Django
I'm configuring a soap service in Django, but when running runserver, it gives me an error from the spyne.six.moves module. Has anyone had this problem or something similar that can help me?
The version of my technologies.
Python 3.12
Spy 2.14
Execute server - response

Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.
